# Trying to pass data from step1's processor to step2's processor (Spring Batch)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have followed this documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps

I'm trying to retrieve the information that I received from **step1's processor** in **step2's processor**.

Everything works If I have my @BeforeStep function in the **writer** class of step2.
But I want to get the information in the **processor** class of step2. But in the processor class, @BeforeStep function doesn't even run.

Is this suppose to happen?? @BeforeStep only get hit in the writer class? or there is a way to get it in the processor class as well??

Answer (score 1):

If you want the method annotated with `@BeforeStep` to be called, you need to declare your component as a Spring bean. Otherwise, you need to register it explicitly as a listener in your step.